# Dell Inspiron-3543 screen lacking vibrance and saturation - how can I calibrate it?

Tags: display, screen, colors, monitor-calibration

After switching from windows 7 to ubuntu I notice that my screen lacks vibrance and saturation. I calibrated it to my liking in W7.

Since it's a laptop Ubuntu is not giving me the option to calibrate the screen. I tried importing ICC's from Windows but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a solution to this? I could even manage with a screen filter that adds saturation, anything that helps bring colors to life.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using `xgamma -gamma 0.7` in terminal.

Comment: Must admit I've played with ICC's off and on without much luck myself. I like your solution though :)